# PHP Satisfaction Survey using submit buttons

Tags: php, forms, submit

I'm working on an automated system for responding to help requests and I want to be able to figure out where or not the clients using it are happy with the responses their getting.

The program should ask them "Where you happy with your response" with yes/no submit buttons under it, when a user submits it should forward them to a designated page and call the sendDebugMessage function (sends us an E-Mail)

Here is the code I worked up to do so but it just redirects to  a blank page:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['Yes'])) {
        ?>
            sendDebugMessage("A user WAS happy with their response!");
            <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://example.com">
        <?php
    } elseif (isset($_POST['No'])) {
        sendDebugMessage("A user was NOT happy with their response!");

        ?>
            <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://example.com">
        <?php
    } else {
        ?>
            Where you happy with this response?
            <form action="" method="post">
                <input type="submit" value="Yes" name="Yes" />
                <input type="submit" value="No" name="No"/>
            </form>
            <br />


        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is `sendDebugMessage` returning any error?

Comment: No it is not giving an errors.

Comment: First `sendDebugMessage` function call, is outside `if`

Comment: @Ander2, Actually, it is outside the php tag, still inside the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain the existing problem, but I guess it's that you will never get "no".

as you are sending both submit buttons within one form, both will get submitted.
so split them like

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="No" name="No"/>
</form>

<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Yes" name="Yes" />
</form>
```

To get different answers.

try `print_r($_POST);` to see if you get any Post vars at all.

**A better solution in my opinion:**

use GET Links like

```
<a href="index.php?answer=yes">yes</a>
<a href="index.php?answer=no">no</a>
```

and read them via the `$_GET[answer]` variable.
so in index.php you would read your vars like

```
<?
  if($_GET[answer] == 'yes'){
    //action for yes
  }
  elseif($_GET[answer] == 'no'){
    //action for no
  }
?>
```

A slightly better working method would be to do it via javascript.

Comment: The issue is that it doesn't seem that the if statements for the "issets" are ever triggered as I never receive an E-Mail nor does the user get redirected. I've also separated the forms and it's still not working.

Comment: have you tried using the simple links that i explained below? like `<a href="index.php?answer=yes">yes</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the action attribute from your form to see if that helps, this is valid html5, and also better for html4 in order to avoid browser issues with an empty action attribute.

Also, make sure you test that your condition - if(isset($_POST... is true by replacing your code inside the brackets with a simple message ie: echo "form submitted!".

*EDIT* Ill assume your sendDebugMessage() function is a javascript function. In that case you need to put it inside a script tag -> `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`.

Comment: I don't see any response when I do that.

Comment: Do you see any response at all? Have you tried print_r($_POST); like daniel suggested? You should not assume that your sendDebugMessage function works, instead echo out a message/or print out the contents of $_POST first to verify that the form is indeed submitted.